# Springboot service logic to compare a particular table data difference which is present in two oracle database

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, datasource, spring-jdbc

Springboot service logic to compare a particular table data difference which is present in two oracle database.

Table "T_HANDLING" will be present in both database - say PROD and DR ..
so this service should tell whether the table data is in synch or not between main and DR database.
If possible email report on the difference in data.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.